# upload video from Iphone application on .NET server using webservice

Tags: iphone, asp.net, web-services, video, file-upload

I have writen client code in Iphone.

```
self.postRequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Services/UploadVideo.asmx"]];

NSString *urlString=[self.videoURL path];
NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);
[self.postRequest setFile:urlString forKey:@"videoUrl"];
[self.postRequest setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[self.postRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.postRequest setDidFailSelector:@selector(postFailed:)];
[self.postRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postSuccessful:)];
[self.postRequest startAsynchronous];

LOG output:// urlString=/private/var/mobile/Applications/09108E9E-1494-4C25-8C3E-328B95BD1504/tmp/capture-T0x1e569fd0.tmp.w37766/capturedvideo.MOV
```

How should I capture it and save it on the server?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to convert the video into nsdata

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:video_url];
```

and then convert the nsdata to base64 string (you need to download the seperate file for base64)

```
NSString *encodedString=[data base64EncodedString];
```

so finally you can send the encoded string to your .net server (you need to decode the encoded string in your .net server to retrieve the video)

Above code is worked for me as image conversion (i think it will work for the video also)

Comment: thanks for help!! but can you suggest me something, which can be use to upload the file directly.

Comment: thats what i have told you in the answer, you just need to convert the video into base64 and then you can send the base64 string to your server as post paramater, thats it